# Does Yahoo prevents checking online/offline status?

Tags: php, chat, status, yahoo-api, yahoo-messenger

I want to add yahoo chat icon inside my website. To detect ID status (online/offline), and opening messenger tool, I've wrote the PHP codes below (given from a website). But it always returns ID is offline. Does Yahoo prevents checking status? What's the problem?

```
<?php
$yahoo_id = 'some_id';
$getstatus = file_get_contents('http://mail.opi.yahoo.com/online?u='.$yahoo_id.'&m=a&t=1');
switch($getstatus) {
    case "00": $status = '<img src="images/yahoo_offline.png" />';
    break;
    case "01": $status = '<a href="ymsgr:sendIM?'.$yahoo_id.'"><img src="images/yahoo_online.png" /></a>';
    break;
}
echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: Tried it just now and looks like it's working. Btw, you can also use [YQL statement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.messenger.status%20where%20u%3D%27joemplumber%27%3B&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys), although it's more complicated than the solution you found.

Comment: @Sutandiono, I tried it. I think it does not work correctly always. My Yahoo ID is online right now, but it returns status as offline.

Comment: And you have your online status set as visible to anyone on the web in your account settings?